# how to pass an id back in the jquery-file-upload response?

Tags: jquery, grails, jquery-file-upload

I am in the process of rewriting a file upload page to use the jquery-file-upload plugin. The server (and page) are grails-based, and the form has two "input type='files'" fields. Files from both fields are automatically uploaded to the server.

I am using just the basic jquery.fileupload.js file (not the -ui version). Here is the file-upload list of resources that I am loading:

```
'jquery-file-upload' {
    dependsOn 'jquery'
    resource url: 'libs/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js'
    resource url: 'libs/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js'
    resource url: 'libs/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-process.js'
    resource url: 'libs/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js'
    resource url: 'libs/jquery-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js'
    resource url: 'libs/javascript-templates/js/tmpl.min.js'
    resource url: 'libs/jquery-file-upload/css/jquery.fileupload.css'

}
```

On the server side,  I have created a FileMeta class which is rendered back to the client as json.

My problem is that there are times when I want to return some additional information back to the client to use in the fileuploaddone event.  I can't figure out how to do that.  I had assumed that whatever I rendered as json in my FileMeta class would be returned in the data,  but it doesn't seem to be.

For example, my FileMeta class has the following fields:

```
private String name;
private String size;
private String type;
private String error;
private String solutionId;
private String token;
```

But when I access data.files in fileuploaddone,  I don't see the same data that was returned from the server. I get values for name, size and type only.  I had manually set strings into type, error, solutionId and token-- they were either overwritten or ignored. Here is what the fileuploaddone currently does:

```
 upForm.on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) { // invoke callback method on success
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) { //loop though each file
        if (file.name){ //successful upload returns a file url
            alert("done with " + file.name);
            alert("solutionId is " + file.solutionId);
            alert("type is " + file.type);
            alert("size is " + file.size);
            alert("error is " + file.error);
            alert("token is " + file.token);
            jQuery('#solutionId').val(file.solutionId);

        } else if (file.error) {
            alert("error is " + file.error);
            var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error); //error text
           alert(error);
        }
    });

});
```

Clearly something is processing the returned json.  Any tips on where that processing is happening, or on how it can be overwritten would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with this line in the uploaddone callback:

```
  $.each(data.files, function (index, file) { //loop though each file
```

data.files is a specific construct for the jquery-upload-done widget.  When I replaced it with data.result  the returned results became available. So, just confusion on my part.